# How to get business page with facebook graph api and laravel socialite package?

Tags: php, laravel, facebook-graph-api, laravel-socialite

I use laravel socialite package to use facebook graph api and i want to get business page or business account information that associed on an simple facebook account

I use this endpoint `"https://graph.facebook.com/user_id/accounts"` to get all info about an user with page and it works perfectly but i want to get all business page or my business account information from this `user_id`.

I have tried to use this (empty data response):

```
$response = $fb->get(
    '/{user-id}/business_users',
    '{access-token}'
  );
```

or this (getting (#100) Missing Permission error) :

```
$response = $fb->get(
    '/{user-id}/businesses',
    '{access-token}'
  );
```

Thanks for your helps

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/business/?locale=pt_BR

Comment: I show this but i want to use user account id instead of business id :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, need to add a 'business_management' scopes.